# Replace using gsub

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm having some problem replacing a partial of a string with another string.

I want this string `"this-is-a-string.jpg"` to be replaced with `"this-is-a-hash.jpg"`.
The `string` value can be any value.

This is what I've so far.

```
str = "this-is-a-string.jpg"
str.gsub(/([a-z]+)[^\.]+?$/i, "hash")
# => "this-is-a-string.hash"
```

Comment: will `this-is-a` stay the same?

Comment: @Gwilym No, the only part that is static is `.jpg`.

Comment: Do you know what the mappings are? I.e. do you know exactly what values change, and to what?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What's the point of changing only one word `string`, while you mentioned, that the static part is only `.jpg`? Do you need to change every occurrence of pattern `string` to word `hash` or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with [rubular](http://www.rubular.com) and I came up with a regexp which works if you don't mind adding a dot manually to the replacement.
Here is what I came up with

```
"this-is-a-string.jpg".gsub(/\w+\./, 'hash.')
```

So I guess you could make a simple function which replaces it like

```
def replace_string(string_to_replace, replacement)
  string_to_replace(/\w+\./, "#{replacement}.")
end
```

in ruby 1.9.2 I managed to extract the word "string" but I don't know if that is of any use to you.

```
  /[-\w]+\-(?<word>(\w+))\.\w+/ =~ "this-is-a-string.jpg"
=> 0
  word
=> "string"
```

I hope I've helped you and given the information you needed